# For testcafe HTML Report can we remove the browser column

Tags: html, testing, automated-tests, testcafe, easyhtmlreport

Can we configure testcafe HTML report as per our requirement?
is it possible to remove the browser column from the report?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a suggestion in the [`testcafe-reporter-html` GitHub repository](https://github.com/picuscreative/testcafe-reporter-html). Also, you can create your own fork, implement the required functionality, and use it in your project.